# Question about inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space with $\langle\ ,\, \rangle$ inner product and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Suppose $\|u\| = \|v\| \implies \|Tu\| = \|Tv\|$  $\forall u, v \in V$.
>
> Show that $\langle Tu, Tv\rangle = \langle u, v\rangle\ \forall u, v \in V$.

I think I almost got it. Let $B=\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$. Then all I must do is to show that $\langle Tv_i, Tv_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$. I have done it for $i\neq j$ (using the polarization identity) but i'm having trouble on showing that $\forall j\ \|Tv_j\| = 1$.

Comment: I think you mean you must show that $\langle Tv_i, Tv_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: As written, this cannot be right: Consider the operator defined by $Tv=2v$ for all $v$. This is clearly a linear operator, and from $||u||=||v||$ it follows that $||2u||=||2v||$. However we do *not* have $\langle 2u,2v\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle$ unless $\langle u,v\rangle=0$.

Comment: The conclusion of the question is incorrect. You can only expect that there exists $c\ge 0$, such that $\langle Tu,Tv\rangle=c\langle u,v\rangle$, $\forall u,v\in V$.

Comment: Note that $||v_1||=||v_2||=\ldots$, so the last condition can be applied quite directly.

Comment: Yes, I think that the question is incorrect :S

Comment: @celtschk Can you convert your comment into an answer (if you don't feel comfortable about receiving reputation, you can make your answer community wiki)?  That way, we can take this question off the unanswered list.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon: OK, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, this cannot be right: Consider the operator defined by $Tv=2v$ for all $v$. This is clearly a linear operator, and from $||u||=||v||$ it follows that $||2u||=||2v||$. However we do not have $⟨2u,2v⟩=⟨u,v⟩$ unless $⟨u,v⟩=0$.